# Codename One build errors related to Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, codenameone

While trying to build an iOS debug version of my app, I came across the following build error. I have imported Kotlin support library but have not actually added any Kotlin code to my app. Where is this error coming from?

```
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_Deprecated no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_ExtensionFunctionType no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_Metadata no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_ReplaceWith no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_Suppress no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_UnsafeVariance no class definition   
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_annotation_MustBeDocumented no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_annotation_Repeatable no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_annotation_Retention no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_annotation_Target no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_internal_Exact no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_internal_HidesMembers no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_internal_InlineExposed no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_internal_InlineOnly no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_internal_LowPriorityInOverloadResolution no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_internal_NoInfer no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_internal_OnlyInputTypes no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_internal_PureReifiable no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_JvmField no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_JvmMultifileClass no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_JvmName no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_JvmOverloads no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_JvmStatic no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_JvmSuppressWildcards no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_JvmSynthetic no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_JvmVersion no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_JvmWildcard no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_PurelyImplements no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_Strictfp no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_Synchronized no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_Throws no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_Transient no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:kotlin_jvm_Volatile no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:org_jetbrains_annotations_Mutable no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:org_jetbrains_annotations_NotNull no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:org_jetbrains_annotations_Nullable no class definition
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:org_jetbrains_annotations_ReadOnly no class definition
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the kotlin support library from the extension manager?

Comment: Codename One extensions? Yes.

Comment: On what IDE are you trying Kotlin?

Comment: Installed on Intellij

Comment: Did you install the kotlin support library from the extension manager as explained here https://www.codenameone.com/blog/kotlin-support-public-beta.html did you refresh libs afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I followed instructions and refreshed the cn1 libs.

Comment: How did you create the project? Did you create it as a standard hello world Codename One project or did you do something else? Did you modify the modules in any way? Are you using the standard IntelliJ IDE? Notice that Android Studio doesn't work.